# Login screen is not appearing

Tags: boot, nvidia, login, 20.04

I updated ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 a day ago and now when i am trying to open ubuntu it's showing

*/dev/nvme0n1p6: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 209996/11567104 files, 7818664/46240512 blocks*

Now what to do

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're after support you should use a #ubuntu+1 site as *focal fossa* hasn't been release yet, however if you're QA-testing and are seeking help with bug reporting, you can also use #ubuntu-quality on IRC or telegram; for help with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not enough information to help you can do the following steps see if it fixes or give us more data back.

Step #1:

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type sudo fsck -f /
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
  and reboot

If this doesnt fixed it

boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB

- start gparted and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4
  partition quit gparted open a terminal window
- type sudo fsck -f
  /dev/sdaX # replacing X with the number you found earlier repeat the
  fsck command if there were errors type reboot